# Update Progress Dialog

Tags: java, android, runnable, retrofit2

Good time of the day.
I'm trying to make application which is supposed to upload files to server and display progress of uploading in `ProgressDialog`.

**This is the code i have so far:**
*Create `ProgressDialog` for Uploading Procedure*

```
private void createUploadingDialog(int filesCount) {
    uploadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    uploadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    loadingDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.upload_progress, 0, filesCount));
    loadingDialog.show();
}
```

*Dismiss `ProgressDialog` for Uploading Procedure*

```
private void dismissUploadingDialog() {
    if (uploadingDialog.isShowing())
        uploadingDialog.dismiss();
}
```

*Update `ProgressDialog` for Uploading Procedure*

```
private void updateUploadingDialog(final String dialogMessage) {
    class UpdateDialog implements Runnable {
        private String messageString;
        private UpdateDialog(String ms) { messageString = ms; }
        public void run() {
            uploadingDialog.setMessage(messageString);
        }
    }
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new UpdateDialog(dialogMessage));
}
```

*Call to create dialog*

```
createUploadingDialog(imagesPathsArray.size());
```

*Call to dismiss dialog*

```
dismissUploadingDialog();
```

*Call to update dialog onSuccess*

```
updateUploadingDialog(getString(R.string.upload_progress, i, imagesPathsArray.size()));
```

*Call to update dialog onFailure*

```
updateUploadingDialog(getString(R.string.retrying_request));
```

The dialog is displayed in fragment. To send images to server i'm using Retrofit2.

When i do initial setup of dialog, message get set correctly (showing total files and current one), however, message is not updating when the update call is made. For some reason, no error is thrown and if i'm adding `Log.d`, it even shows that method was called.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you should read this .This will you help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling update progress only once ,  how are you listning to progress state change listener?, if you want to use that you have to continuously call updateUploadingDialog which is not a good procedure

You have to write upload procedure in asynctask and update progress in onProgressUpdate()  method

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200453/android-upload-file-to-server-with-progressbar-using-service) and [here](http://androstock.com/tutorials/create-a-file-uploader-with-progress-in-android-android-studio.html) are example for reference

on preExecute  initialize the progress bar, in doinbackground upload the file, in onProgressUpdate  update the progress bar and on postexecute  do what ever you want to do after upload

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As per you are not using AsyncTask, you can't get the opportunity of onProgressUpdate feature. So, you have to update your progress bar status manually like using own thread and you have already do. But, I solved my problem using below source code, you can check it:

```
  private void createThread(){
    Runnable runable = new updateProgressStatus();
    progressUpdateThread = new Thread(runnable);
    progressUpdateThread.start();
}

public class updateProgressStatus implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(Thread.currentThread()==progressUpdateThread)            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);    
                progressHandler.sendMessage(YOUR MESSAGE );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Interrupt problem
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private Handler progressHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // Now, update your progress bar status
        progress.setProgress(message.what);
    }
};
```